# Asana API - get all tasks and completion status

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am trying to use the Asana API to get all tasks within a project, as well as whether they have been completed. This seems to require the use of the `opt_expand` parameter, but I am having no luck with the following URL (and combinations of it): `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/XXXX/tasks?limit=10&fields=completed&opt_expand=completed`. Is this possible with the Asana API currently?

Comment: What do you mean by "having no luck?" What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: I am attempting to return all tasks related to a project, and for each of those tasks whether it has been completed (ie returning a field completed, with a value of true or false, attached to each task)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `opt_fields` parameter in your GET request.  Asana does not support generalized queries like `completed=true`.  However, you can query for all tasks for a particular project and then filter the tasks by their `completed_at` value.  The `completed_at` field will return a read-only time (e.g.`'2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z'`) of when the task was completed or `null` if the task is incomplete.

To return all tasks related to a project, including if they are complete, use this GET request: `/projects/XXXX/tasks?opt_fields=name,completed_at`.

For your reference, you can specify the options you want returned by using the parameters outlined in the [Asana Input/Output Option docs](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options).  Also make sure to read the [Asana Tasks docs](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks) to see which fields are available for the task resource.